# Wordpress Header CSS Issue

Tags: css, wordpress, header

I've been working on the following site (http://tinyurl.com/lp5qtkc) and I cannot figure out how to remove the space between the header and the content. I have tried removing the page title that is above it, but the content slides up and the content box remains in the same position. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the .whitebackground CSS class to

```
.whitebackground {
    top: 190px; /* 100px less than what it was */
}
```

And also update the JavaScript (found inside the templatesjs.php file on line 242) executing at 500ms intervals which updates the height of the background so that the content at the bottom of the page renders correctly.

```
setInterval(function() {

  jQuery('.tiledbackground').height(jQuery(document).height());
  jQuery('.whitebackground').height(main_cont.outerHeight()-39); // 100px more

},500);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a div with the class name 'whitebackground' you can play with it position to cover the gap in between.

Like this:

```
.whitebackground{
    top: 190px;
}
```

Please use inspect element option of your browser to debug issues like this.